# Cannot start any virtual machine from VM Player

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware, centos

I am using a Desktop PC with Windows 7 as Operating system. I am using VM PLayer to run a CentOS for me. I am going to use CentOS to setup an Asterisk environment for me so I can conduct studies on it. But when I install / create a new Virtual Machine, I get the error below:

> Error while powering on: The virtual machine could not start. Make
>   sure VMware Player is installed correctly. You must also have rights
>   to run the software and access all directories the software uses,
>   including directories in which the software is installed, directories
>   containing the virtual disk and configuration files, and directories
>   for temporary files.

Any Ideas what causing it? I have searched the internet for solutions but still no solutions worked. I also tried using an existing CentOS-virtual machine which I made from my friends computer (his installation worked) but it shows the same error. Thanks!

Comment: try reinstalling your VMware. Because as per your error, it's saying "make sure VMware Player is installed correctly".

Comment: Tried it number of times. Didn't worked.

Comment: Have you also checked the permissions of the folder. I mean in Program Files and My Documents(or wherever your VM's are stored)?

Comment: I did. Same output. Granted all users for Full Control on both Virtual Machine folder and the VM Player folder itself. It still shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and it turned out to be a process left running after I'd closed the VM previously. I killed the 'vmx' process in Task Manager and the VM started OK.